# Use clang-tidy on CUDA source files

Tags: c++, cuda, clang, static-analysis, clang-tidy

Several static analysis tools designed for C/C++ exist, but they are not particularly useful for testing CUDA sources.

Since [clang version 6](https://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html) is able to compile CUDA, I wanted to check what are my options with using clang-tidy, which does not seem to have option for switching architectures.

Is there a way to make it work? For example compile time switch for turning on CUDA parser, extension in form of custom check, or is it maybe planned feature?

Answer (score 4):

One of the problem with the clang-based tools is that they are *not* parsing the files in exactly the same way as clang does.

The first problem is that unlike C/C++ compilation, CUDA compilation compiles the source multiple times. By default clang creates multiple compilation jobs when you give it a CUDA file and that trips many tools that expect only one compilation. In order to work that around you need to pass `--cuda-host-only` option to clang-tidy.

You may also need to pass `--cuda-path=/path/to/your/CUDA/install/root` so clang can find CUDA headers.

Another problem you may run into would be related to include paths. Clang-derived tools do not have the same default include paths that clang itself uses and that occasionally causes weird problems. At the very least clang-tidy needs to find `__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h` which is installed along with clang. If you run `clang-tidy your-file.c -- -v` it will print clang's arguments and include search paths it uses. Compare that to what `clang -x c /dev/null -fsyntax-only -v`prints. You may need to give `clang-tidy` extra include paths to match those used by `clang` itself. Note that you should **not** explicitly add the path to the CUDA includes here. It will be added in the right place automatically by `--cuda-path=...`.

Once you have it all in place, clang-tidy should work on CUDA files.

Something like this:
`clang-tidy your-file.cu -- --cuda-host-only --cuda-path=... -isystem /clang/includes -isystem /extra/system/includes`

Comment: Ok, thanks - I'll try to experiment with that. Do you expect that I can make it work also for device code?

Comment: Probably, but my guess is that you don't need to. The host/device differences mostly kick in during code generation. clang-tidy does not get there (I think it passes `-fsyntax-only` under the hood) and should give you about the same results for host and device code (modulo things that depend on __CUDA_ARCH__).